# Link's area where all mouse events are possible

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jointjs

I have some problems with links interaction in jointjs

I just set a defaultLink but all mouse events disappeared and I can't interact with links anymore.

The hover event doesn't highlight a connection line with default gray background too.

here is the paper initialization:

```
this.schemePaper = this.JointService.createPaper({
        el: $(this.containers.svgContainer),
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        model: this.graph,
        gridSize: 16,
        perpendicularLinks: true,
        currentScale: this.currentScale,
        drawGrid: true,
        snapLinks: {
            radius: 75
        },
        markAvailable: true
    });

createPaper(paperOptions) {
    const options = Object.assign({}, paperOptions, {
        defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({
            attrs: this.links.simple
        })
    });
    return new joint.dia.Paper(options);
}

this.links = {
        simple: {
            '.connection': {
                stroke: this.linkColor
            },
            '.connection-wrap': {
                'stroke-width': 30
            }
        },
        dashed: {
            '.connection': {
                stroke: this.linkColor,
                'stroke-dasharray': '5, 5'
            }
        }
    };
```

mouseenter event works only when I hover my mouse on a 1px stroke-width connection line

Here is an example:
[the link example without any tools and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKONM.png)

I think that it should be smth with .connection-wrap

I will really appreciate any help, thank you!!

P.S. 
I didn't change the markup

Comment: just wondering where you added the source and target when you create links

Comment: @VinayPrabhakaran, what do you mean? I didn't understand that sorry

Comment: have you tried as in the documentation      defaultLink: new joint.dia.Link({
            attrs: { '.marker-target': { d: 'M 10 0 L 0 5 L 10 10 z' } }
        }),